# Writing access violation while using qsort()

Tags: c++, qsort

I  am using qsort c++ function. I am passing wordArr in my insert function. The objective is to sort the letters for each word belonging to wordArr.However, while using qsort, I get write access violation. Please let me know, where is my mistake.

```
char* wordArr[]={"cat","bat","dog"};

int tableClass::compChar(const void* a, const void* b)//in my header file this is static
{
    return *(const char*)a - *(const char*)b;
}
void tableClass::insert(char* wordArr[],const int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        qsort(wordArr[i], strlen(wordArr[i]), sizeof(char),tableClass::compChar);

    }   

}
```

Comment: if you're using this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/ then the arguments are wrong. Double check them

Comment: On top of that I believe you're modifying string constants which will give a bus error.

Comment: Why does anyone want to use `qsort` in C++? There is `std::sort` which is faster *and* safer. Also, you should get a warning for the conversion from `"cat"` to `char*` as Jesus Ramos points out.

Comment: I have used std:sort and i get the same error

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to modify string literals, you can't do that. You need to make copies of the strings.

Answer (score 3):

Your code attempts to sort the characters of each string.

```
char* wordArr[] = { "cat", "bat", "dog" };
```

Is an array of pointers to string literals. No matter that you store the location of those character literals as `char*` and not as `char const*` (which is only possible due to the wish of the c++ standards committee to preserve backwards compatibility), changing a string literal causes undefined behavior.

In your case, the storage for the string literals will be allocated in read only memory, leading to an access violation when you attempt to write it.

By storing the string literals in memory under your own control, the access violation does not happen:

```
char cat[] = "cat";
char bat[] = "bat";
char dog[] = "dog";
char* wordArr[]={cat, bat, dog};
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code:

1) The parameters are wrong, look at the documentation

2) You're trying to modify read-only memory by reordering an array of pointers to strings allocated into a read-only area. That is not allowed and can result in **undefined behavior**, i.e. anything could happen.

I would suggest using [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) for this kind of things and possibly use a stl vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void sort_stuff(std::vector<std::string>& arr)
{

    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
}

bool myfunction (char *i,char *j) {

    int res = strcmp(i,j); // Needed to compare all characters

    return (res < 0) ? true : false; // Weak ordering criterion
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    arr.push_back("cat");
    arr.push_back("dog");
    arr.push_back("bat");

    sort_stuff(arr);

        // --- edit: if you really want to use a char array ---

    char cat[] = "cat";
    char bat[] = "bat";
    char dog[] = "dog";
    char* wordArr[]={cat, bat, dog};
    sort(wordArr, wordArr+sizeof(wordArr)/sizeof(char*), myfunction);
    cout << wordArr[0] << wordArr[1] << wordArr[2];

    return 0;
}
```

Try it live: http://ideone.com/ErEWnb

---

Edit: I'm not sure why you really want to use a char array but in case you really need it, you should

1) Put those into writeable memory (e.g. local memory, not string literals)
2) Specify the comparison function since if you pass a char pointers array straight away to `sort` you would compare the pointers instead of the data they point to. And make sure you compare all characters of the strings. strcmp does what you want

```
bool myfunction (char *i,char *j) {

    int res = strcmp(i,j); // Needed to compare all characters

    return (res < 0) ? true : false; // Weak ordering criterion
}

...

char cat[] = "cat";
char bat[] = "bat";
char dog[] = "dog";
char* wordArr[]={cat, bat, dog};
sort(wordArr, wordArr+sizeof(wordArr)/sizeof(char*), myfunction);
cout << wordArr[0] << wordArr[1] << wordArr[2];
```

Comment: Thank you, so in my qsort function do I have to pass a copy of string ie wordArr[i] ?

Comment: either use a vector or allocate the strings into an area where you can write (e.g. into an array into your function, **not** a char pointer to a string literal)

Comment: I am aware of using the vector for this,but  i also wanted to try it this way.I am stuck at creating an array though?

Comment: @user3598049 added info if you really want to use char arrays. Please read it up

Comment: Your `myfunction()` is not correct. The compare function for `std::sort` must provide a __strict weak ordering__ and should return `false` on equality. You can just change the condition to `res < 0` to fix it.

Comment: You're right thanks, fixed. It's also faster this way :)